# Get the layer given a feature in open layers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

How do you get a feature's layer in open layers 3?

[Past versions](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Feature-js.html) of open layers had a *layer* property on each *feature*. This made it easy to apply layer specific styling to features or to organize features by layer.

Open layers 3 is missing this property. I'm using [ol.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel](http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel) to get features on hover.

```
    // Loop through all features a given pixel
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        console.log(layer);
        return feature;      // just return the first feature
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to answer my own question in case others are having this issue. 
[OL3 forum disscussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ol3-dev/selected%2420feature%2420source/ol3-dev/AvUBWFvehHY/MY34600amM8J) on this.

The solution here to to follow the OL3 hover [example](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/vector-layer.html?q=hover) and pass in a layer to the [ol.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel](http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel) function. This paramater is not in the documentation so it's hard to find, but it will get you the layer. I'm not sure how this interacts with features on multiple layers.

```
   // Loop through all features at this pixel but just return the top level feature
    var fl = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return {'feature':feature, 'layer':layer};
    });

    var feature = fl.feature,   feature
        layer = fl.layer;
```

Comment: Helpful. Presumably, you use the options array parameter to determine which feature to interact with. The full function call being: forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, callback, opt_this, opt_layerFilter, opt_this2)